# Dask Does between_time exist?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

In pandas there is the [between_time method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) however my dataset is too large for pandas, however doing a quick control f in [the Dask api](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html) shows 4 mentions for between_time but no actual use of it.

I just get a lovely: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'between_time'. Does it actually exist? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  As of 2018-09-02 no `between_time` method exists for Dask Dataframes.  It is not listed as a function in the [Dask dataframe API](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html)